# Circus WEBUI is not working

Tags: python, circusd

I have the following `circus` config:

```
[circus]
pidfile       = /tmp/circus.pid
check_delay   = 5
statsd        = True
httpd         = True
httpd_host    = 10.3.2.1
httpd_port    = 8888
endpoint      = tcp://127.0.0.1:5555
pubsub_endpoint = tcp://127.0.0.1:5556
stats_endpoint  = tcp://127.0.0.1:5557
stream_backend  = thread

[watcher:my_app]
working_dir   = /var/www/my_app/
cmd           = /usr/local/bin/waitress-serve
args          = --unix-socket='/tmp/my_app.socket' --threads=16 --http_app:main
uid           = www-data
gid           = www-data
numprocesses  = 1
warmup_delay  = 0
use_sockets   = True
graceful_timeout = 2
stderr_stream.class = StdoutStream
```

It seems to work at first:

```
# circusd circus.ini
2016-12-02 18:21:15 circus[6406] [INFO] Starting master on pid 6406
2016-12-02 18:21:15 circus[6406] [INFO] sockets started
2016-12-02 18:21:15 circus[6406] [INFO] Arbiter now waiting for commands
2016-12-02 18:21:15 circus[6406] [INFO] my_app started
2016-12-02 18:21:15 circus[6406] [INFO] circusd-stats started
2016-12-02 18:21:15 circus[6406] [INFO] circushttpd started
2016-12-02 18:21:16 circus[6414] [INFO] Starting the stats streamer
Serving on http://unix:/tmp/my_app.socket
2016-12-02 18:21:16 circus-web[6415] [INFO] Starting circus web ui on fd 6
```

But then if I try to connect to the `endpoint` (*127.0.0.1:5555*) from the `WEBUI`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1425, in _stack_context_handle_exception
    raise_exc_info((type, value, traceback))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 314, in wrapped
    ret = fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1638, in future_complete
    f.result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 237, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 285, in wrapper
    yielded = next(result)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/circusweb/circushttpd.py", line 164, in post
    endpoints = self.get_arguments('endpoint_list', [])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/web.py", line 412, in get_arguments
    assert isinstance(strip, bool)
AssertionError
```

What could be wrong? Seems like a bug in `circus` code.

Answer (score 1):

There's a [cure](https://github.com/circus-tent/circus-web/pull/63/commits/e824d1a5c2de3431f0d8ea62134ecb40f9f1ad95):

```
 @@ -161,11 +161,11 @@ def get(self):
      @gen.coroutine
      def post(self):
          endpoints_list = list(self.session.endpoints)
 -        endpoints = self.get_arguments('endpoint_list', [])
 +        endpoints = self.get_arguments('endpoint_list')

          # If no selection in list
          if not endpoints:
 -            endpoints = self.get_arguments('endpoint_direct', [])
 +            endpoints = self.get_arguments('endpoint_direct')

          if not endpoints:
              self.redirect(self.reverse_url('disconnect'))
```

It's a shame it didn't find its way to `pip`.